# Using Polly to retry on different Urls after failing retries

Tags: c#, .net-core, polly

I'm working on a proof of concept in .Net Core and new to polly and struggling to understand how to do configure it in such a way as to define a retry policy but after this fails we switch to a different url and retry on this (there may be a number of these and the list of available Urls is dynamic)

My preference is to use the HttpClientFactory and Typed Clients as described here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#typed-clients

I've looked at 
https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/199

https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/591

But cannot how to see how to apply these to a dynamic list and within the HttpClientFactory/ Typed Client approach

```
// Attempting to enable dynamic clients
// https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/199
// https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/591 using HttpClientfactory


 services.AddHttpClient<IAppointmentServiceClient, AppointmentServiceClient>()
                .ConfigureHttpClient((serviceProvider, client) =>
{
                    var serverList = ServiceRegistration.LocateServiceList("AppointmentService").Result;
                    var random = new Random();
                    int index = random.Next(serverList.Count);
                    var baseAddress = new Uri($"http://{ serverList[index]}");


                    client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
                })
                .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy())

                //.AddPolicyHandler(GetCircuitBreakerPolicy());
                .AddPolicyHandler((sp, req, key) =>
                {
                    return GetCircuitBreakerPolicy();
                },
                GetPolicyKey
                );
}


static string GetPolicyKey(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
{
 return httpRequestMessage.RequestUri.Authority;
}


static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
{
       return HttpPolicyExtensions
              .HandleTransientHttpError()
              .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
              .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
                onRetryAsync: async (outcome, timespan, retryCount, context) => {
                    context["RetriesInvoked"] = retryCount; // allows us to capture the reties downstream, potential for extra logging 

                });

}

static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()
        {
            return HttpPolicyExtensions
                .HandleTransientHttpError()
                .CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 
                    onBreak: (ex, breakDelay, context) =>
                    {

                    },
                    onReset: (context)=> 
                    {

                    },
                    onHalfOpen: () => { }
                );
}
```

The actual call is just

```
public AppointmentServiceClient(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _apiClient = httpClient;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<AppointmentEntity>> GetResourceAppointments(string resourceId, DateTimeOffset date)
        {

            var url = GetResourceAppointmentsUrl(resourceId, date);

            var context = new Polly.Context();
            //context["baseUrls"] = _serverList;

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            request.SetPolicyExecutionContext(context);
            var response = await _apiClient.SendAsync(request);

            context = response.RequestMessage?.GetPolicyExecutionContext(); // (if not already held in a local variable)
            //if (context?.TryGetValue("RetriesInvoked", out int? retriesNeeded) ?? false)
            //{
            //    // Do something with int? retriesNeeded
            //}


            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var appointmentResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AppointmentEntity>>(appointmentResponse);
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at the `ConfigureHttpClient` extension method of `HttpClientFactory`. It lets you configure the `HttpClient` that the factory is creating.

Here is something you could try -

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddSingleton<IMyUrlList, MyUrlList>();

    services.AddHttpClient("RemoteServer", client =>
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    }).ConfigureHttpClient((serviceProvider, client) =>
    {
        IMyUrlList myUrlList = serviceProvider.GetService<IMyUrlList>();
        client.BaseAddress = myUrlList.NextUrl();
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

It is based on [something I wrote](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2018/12/dynamically-updating-the-request-header-of-a-httpclientfactory-generated-httpclient-part-2/) that changes the a header header in a request at runtime.